# How to exclude a dependency from nuget package in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

I have a solution that consume a nuget that have all DTO classes(DataObjects).

When developing I want to create new DTO's. To avoid to have to add the DTO to the external project DataObjects and recompile and republish the nuget just to have access to the new DTO in my project, I have created a project(DevObjects) that have the same namespace.
I just pop a new DTO class into DevObjects and continue developing.
When I'm done with that particular job I move the DTO to the DataObjects recompile and publish the nuget.

This works fine except that when I publish the the library that I was working on as a nuget, it list DevObjects as a dependency even thou it is not referenced in code.

How can I exclude DevObjects from the library nuget?

The only workaround I can think of is to publish a dummy nuget of DevObjects just to make nuget happy, but it does not feel like a palatable solution.

Comment: Hi, l want to know how you move the DTO class into DataProjects, did you use projectreference? Also, l wonder whether your project is based on framework or standard. Besides, do you want to remove the dependency without using the DTO which is included in the DevObjects?

Comment: Simplest possible way. I move the file. The DevObjects is just used as a temp storage to avoid to have to mess with the external project. After moving the DTO to DataProjects I update the nuget and update the project to include the new nuget package and then the DTO is accessible from there.

Comment: The project is .net standard.

Comment: How did you move DTO into DataProjects, using ProjectReference to reference the project DevObjects  or  add an existing item?

Comment: I don't have DataProjects.

Comment: Did you try to use Assembly Reference to reference the DevObject.dll(browse into DevObject and choose the bin folder file `DevObject.dll`).

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm done with that particular job I move the DTO to the
>   DataObjects recompile and publish the nuget.

I think you have added project reference like **DevObjects** which contains the file DTO into **DataObjects** project Also, l think the projects are based on Net Standard. When you package **DataObjects**, it will generate the dependency to **DevObjects**. This is the normal behavior.

In a way, when you package the project as nuget, the generation of dependencies really means adding project references.

> How can I exclude DevObjects from the library nuget?

You can just remove DevObjects by some changes into DataObjects.csproj

**>** change the `include` into `remove`

```
 <ProjectReference Remove="..\xxxx\DevObjects.csproj" />
```

**Besides**, you can exclude the reference project by UI Control.(`Right-click on DataObjects-->Dependencies-->Add Reference-->Projects-->uncheck DevObjects`)

**Conclusion**

When you package a project, the Project Reference adds a dependency to your nuget package. So if you do not want to have this dependency, you can just add the DTO class as an Existing Item into **DataObjects** project. Hope it could help you.

Comment: No DataObjects have no knowlege or connections to DevObjects. They are completely separated.
And it is the Library(lib) I work on that have the dependency to DevObjects not DataObjects. So when I add the lib nuget to use it somewhere it also installs the DataObjects nuget as it should. But then it complains that it can’t find the DevObject nuget which is understandable sense it has never existed. DevObjects is just a dll shared by project in Visual studio. And for some reason Visual studio believe that the shared dll is a nuget package and add it as something that should be pulled from nuget.

Comment: First, try to clean the nuget cache(`Tools-->Options-->Nuget Package Manger-->General-->Clean Nuget Cache`) . In addition, when you create net standard([new sdk syle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format)) and reference the DevObject project as dependency, it will list it as dependency(It is designed by that) and is different from framework project. So l think you can use ReferenceAssembly format. Reference the DevObject.dll(after build the DevObject project) by **Add Reference** and then you pack your project and will not see the dependency.

Comment: When you say "Add Reference" do you mean Right click on Dependencies and select Add Reference? That Is how I add the dll to the project now. I add it as a project reference. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Sure. But you cannot use the projectReference(Add Reference-->Projects-->to choose a project).This is like reference a nuget and the system will specify DevObject as a dependency of the current project. Using `Assembly Reference` to reference `DevObject .dll`  is like the content of the project.They are reference content to the project, not a dependency. So when you package projects, they don't have any dependencies. So try to Add Reference-->Browse-->locate to the bin folder of the DevObject  project and then choose `DevObject .dll`(make sure the project has been built).